# Multiple authors emails problem

Tags: formatting

I have multiple authors emails on my paper with the same domain and i need to divide the line below on two lines as it is too long, any help?

```
\documentclass{llncs}

\begin{document}
\title{any title}
\author{John kamdreen,John kamdreen,John kamdreen,John kamdreen,%
  John kamdreen,John kamdreen,John kamdreen}
\institute{Center John kamdreen John kamdreen Research\\
  $\left\{John.kamdreen,John.kamdreen,John.kamdreen,John.kamdreen,%
  John.kamdreen,Jo‌​hn.kamdreen,John.kamdreen\right\}$@dalton.edu.au}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

The document class is available [from the publisher](http://www.springer.com/computer/lncs?SGWID=0-164-6-793341-0).

Comment: I don't know other way to do it

Comment: Based on your comments on the existing answer, we probably need to see the document class, _etc._ Could you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @JosephWright the link to the `.sty` file got posted as a comment on my answer, below. I should have asked for it here, which would have been more useful. Anyway, [here](http://springer.com/computer/lncs?SGWID=0-164-6-793341-0)

Comment: It would be helpful to clarify if you want the functionality of `\left` and `\right` or not. Also, if you're following the `llncs` format, if you look at their documentation, they actually have an `\email{}` macro that is supposed to go inside `\institute{}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @JosephWright has pointed out in his answer, if you all you want are the braces (*i.e.*, `{` and `}`), then you do not need to use `\left` and `\right`. However, if you want the behavior of the `delimiters` then:

When using `delimiters` (*i.e.*, `\left\{` and `\right\}`), you **cannot** put line breaks inside of them. One way around this it to embed the text between the delimiters inside of a `varwidth` environment. (`minipage` works, too, but `varwidth` automatically sets the width of the environment to the width of the content, *i.e.*, setting the width to `12cm` will still only set the width of the `varwidth` environment to the width of the longest line, "John.kamdreen,John.kamdreen,John.kamdreen,John.kamdreen"; see the [`varwidth` documentation](http://ftp.math.purdue.edu/mirrors/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/varwidth/varwidth-doc.pdf).)

If you put such an environment inside the `delimiters`, then you can use manual line breaks inside of that environment:

```
\documentclass{llncs}

\usepackage{varwidth}

\title{any title}
\author{John kamdreen,John kamdreen,John kamdreen,John kamdreen,John kamdreen,John kamdreen,John kamdreen}
\institute{Center John kamdreen John kamdreen Research\\ $\left\{\begin{varwidth}{12cm}\centering John.kamdreen,John.kamdreen,John.kamdreen,\\John.kamdreen,John.kamdreen,John.kamdreen,John.kamdreen\end{varwidth}\right\}$@dalton.edu.au} 

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that I've added `\centering` to center the first line of email addresses. You could remove this if you wish to do so.

Comment: but i have to follow the llncs springer format so i can't do it in your shape, can you do it in the llncs format?

Comment: @sherifHaggag What is the llncs format? Can you provide a link to it, if it is a custom `.sty` file? Better yet, can you please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: http://www.springer.com/computer/lncs?SGWID=0-164-6-793341-0

Comment: \begin{document}
\title{any title}
\author{John kamdreen,John kamdreen,John kamdreen,John kamdreen,John kamdreen,John kamdreen,John kamdreen}
\institute{Center John kamdreen John kamdreen Research\ $\left\{John.kamdreen,John.kamdreen,John.kamdreen,John.kamdreen,John.kamdreen,John.kamdreen,John.kamdreen\right\}$@dalton.edu.au}
\end{document}

Answer (score 5):

If all that is required is to have braces around material, you do not need math mode:

```
\documentclass{llncs}

\begin{document}
\title{any title}
\author{John kamdreen,John kamdreen,John kamdreen,John kamdreen,%
  John kamdreen,John kamdreen,John kamdreen}
\institute{Center John kamdreen John kamdreen Research\\
  \{John.kamdreen,John.kamdreen,John.kamdreen,John.kamdreen,%
  John.kamdreen,\\ Jo‌​hn.kamdreen,John.kamdreen\}@dalton.edu.au}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Note that as you don't have spaces between the e-mail addresses, I've manually added a line break.